# WP_SITEURL variable issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to upload a fully working Wordpress website to some online OVH hosting

On localhost, the files are stored in a "wordpress/" subdirectory, whereas online they are stored in the root "www/" directory so that there is no "wordpress" in any url.

So I have done replacements in the database (this is not the first time I do such a move and last time it worked nicely thanks to good tutorials here or there -- by the way this http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ is really useful)

Still I have spent the whole afternoon unsuccessfully making this website work :

http://www.ditoprod.com/

In fact I need to know more about the WP_SITEURL variable, cf wp_config.php :

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'htp:/www.ditoprod.com' );
```

Actually if I set it to "htp:/www.ditoprod.com/wordpress" the site will not be able to load any image or style because there is no "wordpress" directory, but if I set it to 'htp:/www.ditoprod.com' it will only show a blank page as if there were a php error (the problem here is I cannot find how to access OVH apache error logs unless I upgrade my account ><)

Comment: You should never host files on an account where you don't have access to the logs.  How do you expect to identify problems with your production application? My suggestion is to get access to the logs, which should clearly show you where you are having problems with the application configuration.  You may have been able to resolve this in a few minutes if you had access to your logs.  Without it you are just guessing.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation from WordPress on migrating websites? http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably set `/wordpress` as the home and site URL when you initially set up the site, so the value is stored in the database.  Either change the values in the database or put this into wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.ditoprod.com');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://www.ditoprod.com');
```

There's also a typo in your URL - it's "http" not "htp".